# Freeing a Realloc'd Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, realloc

I am just starting to learn about malloc'd and realloc'd arrays. Can anyone help explain to me how to properly free my following array? I have tried looking at other posts, but I have a hard time understanding memory allocation in C.

```
char ** result = NULL;
int numSpaces = 0;

char * p = strtok(command, " ");

/* split string and append tokens to 'result' */
while (p)
{
    result = realloc (result, sizeof (char*) * ++numSpaces);

    if (result == NULL)
        exit (-1); /* memory allocation failed */

    result[numSpaces-1] = p;

    p = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Freeing `realloc`-ed memory is not different from freeing `malloc`-ed memory, in that all you need is to call `free` on the `result` at the end, when you no longer need the memory.

Your code, however, has a pattern that may lead to a memory leak: you are assigning `realloc`-ed block back to `result` without checking it for `NULL`. If `realloc` fails, the previous value of the `result` becomes unrecoverable, because it has been overwritten by `NULL`.

Here is how you could fix this issue:

```
char **temp = realloc(result, sizeof (char*) * ++numSpaces);

if (temp == NULL) {
    free(result); // Free the old memory block
    exit (-1); /* memory allocation failed */
}
result = temp;
```

Comment: They are checking for that case. `if (result == NULL)`. And they handle it by killing the application.

Comment: @BillLynch They null-check allocation, but that's too late: the old `result` is gone by then.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I was looking at some examples and they had free() in a for loop and other stuff going on so I was a bit unsure. Cheers!

Comment: There is no memory leak, because the code terminates the program when realloc fails.   Worrying about freeing on exit is an operating-system-specific problem. On a system that cleans up processes properly, it's just a waste of cycles to iterate over data structures and free them. For programs that juggle a large number of objects, it can create significant delays in shutdown, especially if they are paged out to disk.

Comment: @Kaz This is a learning exercise, not a production system. It's important to learn the right patterns from the beginning to avoid mistakes when writing production code where the system is not exiting on `realloc` failures, but does something else.

Answer (score 3):

At some point after you are done using `result`, you need to call `free(result);`.

This might look like:

```
char ** result = NULL;
int numSpaces = 0;

char * p = strtok(command, " ");

while (p) {
    result = realloc (result, sizeof (char*) * ++numSpaces);
    result[numSpaces-1] = p;
    p = strtok(NULL, " ");
}

for (i=0; i<numSpaces; ++i)
    printf("word %d: %s\n", i, result[i]);

free(result);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I was looking at some examples and they had free() in a for loop and other stuff going on so I was a bit unsure. Cheers!